# Modify and redraw another UIView from the UIViewController

Tags: ios

I have a flow issue in my iOS app from my subclassed UIView to its parent UIViewController.

Basically, I have a nib called preferences. It contains two sliders, two labels, and another UIView that will display a shape dictated by the two scroll bars (Stroke and opacity). I successfully painted the subclassed ui to the screen by setting the custom class of the UIView to a separate UIView we'll call subView. I have setters/getters for the scroll bars and they print out their values. How do i let the uiview class (pointed at the ui nib object) to update and redraw since it isn't referenced in the parent preferences class? I tried syntax like this:

[code]
IBOutlet SubClassUIView *subclassUI
[/code]

to no effect. It seems best to point a custom class at the UIView.

Any suggestions and advice would be much appreciated.

TL;DR can't modify subclassed uiview from "parent" uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, i figured it out.

In addition to passing in a custom class that shares the same type as the IBOutlet (such as a UIView),

there MUST be a link referencing every object in in the .xib to its parent. In this case, the parent UIViewController needed a reference from the custom class ui to a IBOutlet UI. From there, some simple casting from generic and boring UIView to the custom class's unique methods makes for a complete flow.